# Bloc class instance variables are being refreshed every time I trigger an event

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am trying to access an instance variable inside my Bloc class but every time I am triggering an event, it seems to be refreshed, in other words, the Bloc Class is getting newly instantiated or something. Is there anyway to hold down these values, so that I can access them when ever i need from my bloc class.

Here is my BloC class

```
class DashBoardBloc extends Bloc<DashBoardScreenEvents, DashboardScreenStates> {

  ResponseBusinessSummary? responseBusinessSummary;

  DashBoardBloc()
      : super(DashboardScreenInitial(
            Utils.getInstance().startDate, Utils.getInstance().endDate)) {
    on<GetBusinessSummary>(_getBusinessSummary);
    on<SwitchShiftTerminalCollection>(_switchSalesList);
  }

  _getBusinessSummary(
      GetBusinessSummary event, Emitter<DashboardScreenStates> emit) async {
    var startDate = event.startDate ?? "";
    var endDate = event.endDate ?? "";
    try {
      var token = await SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance()?.getToken();
      var response = await ApiController.getInstance()
          ?.getBusinessSummary(token!, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate);
      if (response != null) {
        if (response.flag!) {
          responseBusinessSummary = response;
          List<ShiftTerminalSaleData> shiftTerminalWiseCollection = response.shiftWiseCollection!;
          String shiftTitle = "Shift Wise Sales";
          emit(DashboardScreenLoaded(response, 0, shiftTitle,
              shiftTerminalWiseCollection, startDate, endDate));
        } else {
          var errorResponse = ResponseBusinessSummary(
              flag: response.flag, messageBag: response.messageBag);
          emit(DashBoardLoadError(startDate, endDate, errorResponse));
        }
      } else {
        var errorResponse = ResponseBusinessSummary(
            flag: false, messageBag: "An Error Occurred!Please Try Again!");
        emit(DashBoardLoadError(startDate, endDate, errorResponse));
      }
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      Utils.debugPrint(e);
      Utils.debugPrint(stacktrace);
      var errorResponse = ResponseBusinessSummary(
          flag: false, messageBag: "An Error Occurred!Please Try Again!");
      emit(DashBoardLoadError(startDate, endDate, errorResponse));
    }
  }

  _switchSalesList(SwitchShiftTerminalCollection event,Emitter<DashboardScreenStates> emit){
    var startDate = event.startDate??"";
    var endDate = event.endDate??"";
    var response = responseBusinessSummary;
    List<ShiftTerminalSaleData> shiftTerminalWiseCollection =
    event.index == 0
        ? response!.shiftWiseCollection!
        : response!.terminalWiseCollection!;
    String shiftTitle = event.index == 0
        ? "Shift Wise Sales"
        : "Terminal Wise Sales";
    emit(ShiftTerminalListChanged(response, 0, shiftTitle,
        shiftTerminalWiseCollection, startDate, endDate));
  }
}
```

I want to access the responseBusinessSummary variable whenever I need without it getting refreshed, what is the solution this?

Link for event classes - https://pastebin.com/iSPKdnHX
Link for state classes - https://pastebin.com/5TG1N9gp